# How to set new joomla template

Tags: templates, joomla

I  have created my own template for Joomla and now I want to apply it to my site. However, when I logged in to the adminstrator --> extensions --> Template Manager, my template was not there. So, I got confused. I already put all of them into an appropriate folder and try to zip them, try other couple of tutorials in the Internet. The Template Manager just does not recognize my template, no error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Joomla 1.6? If so, you may need to "discover" your new template.

This can be done by going to `Extensions -> Extension Manager` and clicking the `Discover` tab at the top. Do a refresh and check if your new template shows up. If it does, then you also have the option to install it from here and then it should show up in the template manager.

Comment: I am using Joomla 1.6, I will check that. Thanks for your help

Comment: That works, thanks. It was so confusing for me and I could not find any document about that extension manager

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a valid templateDetails.xml for the template to show up in the template manager. You do not have to install the template through the installer, you can just upload the files.

Comment: I think my one is correct. I even tried to copy an existing one and just change the folder name, but my localhost system does not recognize the template

Comment: The folder name doesn't affect the template manager. The name tag in the XML file has to be unique or it won't show up in the manager.